# Creatings an HTML Options menu using values from an array?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, mootools

I am creating an array that inserts values into based on user input and would now like to be able to create an drop-down options menu which will contain all of the values that are currently stored in the array.

Would anyone know the correct way of doing this?

BTW Im using jquery and mootools for this site if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
var selectM = document.createElement("select"), values = ["hi", "hello", "hola"];

for(var i = 0; i < values.length; ++i) {
    var opt = document.createElement("option");
    opt.value = values[i];
    opt.text = values[i];
    selectM.add(opt, null);       
}

// do stuff with your new select menu
document.getElementById("someDiv").appendChild(selectM);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use jQuery...

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3];
var $select = $('<select>');
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var val = arr[i];
    $('<option>').val(val).text(val).appendTo($select); // This assumes your array is an primitive type array, if it's an object array you could use ex. val.Value
}

$select.appendTo($('... your selector here ...'));
```

Answer (score 0):

since you have vanilla js and jquery, here's one way to do it via mootools 1.3

```
var makeDropdown = function(vals) {   
    return new Element("select").adopt(vals.map(function(el) {
        return new Element("option[value="+el+"][text="+el+"]");
    }));
};


makeDropdown(["hi", "hello", "hola"]).inject(document.body);
```